# How to calculate width and lengths of street in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am already aware that this question, more specifically, should have been directed to [GIS StackExchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com). I already asked the question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185017/how-to-calculate-width-and-lengths-of-street-layer-in-postgis-postgresql) but sadly, got no answers or any suggestions. I used ST_ClosestPoint() to project a point to the nearest line (point on line interpolation) using this approach.

```
Select  ST_ClosestPoint(line, pt) As closest_pt_line
From
      (Select ad.geom As pt,
              st.geom As line,
              ST_Distance(ad.geom, st.geom) As d
       From ad, st
       Where ST_DWithin(st.geom, ad.geom, 10.0)
       Order By d
      ) As foo;
```

Based on this projected point, I need to calculate the length of street in both directions and width of street by making using of building polygons layer. The scenario can be visualized like this:

[Visualization of the scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxT9E.jpg)

I am aware of ST_Length function but it returns the length of whole linestring rather than length 1 and length 2. Any advice to calculate lengths of street and width would be highly appreciated?